# Which date should I include in personal statement?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application-cover-letter, statement-of-purpose

I have just finished writing personal statement and as far as formal etiquette concerns, there should be a date at the beginning. Is this a date I started writing the statement or the date I am sending it?

And is this the right format of the date: February 24, 2014?

Comment: My personal statement did not include a date, and I don't think a date is required.

Comment: DO you mean a personal statement or cover letter ? As @AruRay points out, personal statements don't typically include a date, but cover letters do.

Comment: It's for Masters studies and it's a personal statement. I think it's always better to include a date. So what do you think? Which date?

Comment: I would probably use the date of when I *finished* writing the statement (which might be earlier than sending), but I don't think there's a rule for that.

Comment: Nobody will care about the date or even notice it (unless it's wildly off).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is for an application for university, then you do not need to date your personal statement. That is because your application as a whole is dated and signed by you at the very end.

Otherwise, you can initialize and date it at the end of the document, e.g.:

KN
2014.06.30